# Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'CONSTRAINT'

Tags: mysql, sql-server

I am getting this error message ...

> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 20
>    Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'CONSTRAINT'.

I've done my research and I'm still stuck on completing this script.

Here`s what I entered.

```
DROP TABLE SEMESTER; 
DROP TABLE CLASS;
DROP TABLE STUDENT;

CREATE TABLE STUDENT (
stuid int not null,
stulname CHAR(40) not null,
stufname CHAR(40) not null,
stugender CHAR(1) not null,
stubirthdate DATE not null);

CREATE TABLE CLASS (
title CHAR(40) not null PRIMARY KEY,
instructor CHAR(40) not null );

CREATE TABLE SEMESTER (
year int not null ); 


CONSTRAINT pk_student PRIMARY KEY (stuid, stulname, stufname, stugender, stubirthdate),
CONSTRAINT pk_class PRIMARY KEY (title, instructor),
CONSTRAINT pk_semester PRIMARY KEY (semid, year));
```

Comment: Knowing whether you are using MySQL or SQL Server would be helpful, and could even explain the error in the first place.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think those `CONSTRAINT` statements need to be *inside* the `CREATE TABLE` statements.  For example, the `STUDENT` table should look like this:

```
CREATE TABLE STUDENT (
    stuid int not null,
    stulname CHAR(40) not null,
    stufname CHAR(40) not null,
    stugender CHAR(1) not null,
    stubirthdate DATE not null,
    CONSTRAINT pk_student PRIMARY KEY (stuid, stulname, stufname, stugender, stubirthdate), 
);
```

Otherwise, how could the RDBMS know to which table each constraint actually belongs?

Answer (score 0):

```
DROP TABLE SEMESTER; 
DROP TABLE CLASS;
DROP TABLE STUDENT;

CREATE TABLE STUDENT (
stuid int not null,
stulname CHAR(40) not null,
stufname CHAR(40) not null,
stugender CHAR(1) not null,
stubirthdate DATE not null
CONSTRAINT pk_student PRIMARY KEY (stuid, stulname, stufname, stugender, stubirthdate),);

CREATE TABLE CLASS (
title CHAR(40) not null ,
instructor CHAR(40) not null ,
CONSTRAINT pk_class PRIMARY KEY (title, instructor));

CREATE TABLE SEMESTER (
year int not null ,
semid int not null
CONSTRAINT pk_semester PRIMARY KEY (semid, year));;
```

AS per my understanding 
Here constraint must be create inside the table for student
and 
second table u are creating 2 times primary key on class(title)
and 
coming to third table semid itself not present in semester table